# Defining functor for this stack type in haskell

Tags: haskell, functor

This is how I have define my Stack type. There could be better ways, but as of now lets stick for this one.

```
data Stack' v = Stack' [v] Int deriving (Show)
```

So something like push' will look like this

```
push' :: (Ord v) => Stack' v -> v -> Stack' v 
push' (Stack' l m) a = if m <= length l then Stack' l m else Stack' (l ++ [a]) m
```

But I am not able to define functor for this. My this attempt is failing saying that "Parse error in pattern: v"

```
instance Functor Stack' where
    fmap f (v l) = (map f v) (l)
```

Can someone help me in defining the functor?

Answer (score 3):

```
instance Functor Stack' where
    fmap f (Stack' v l) = Stack' (map f v) (l)
```

Look at type of `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` and you will find your mistake.

You need to provide a value of type `f a` (here f is Stack') and also return a value of type `f a`.

Also you should try avoiding `++` as it is `O(n)` where n is the length of first argument.

Comment: One way of avoiding `++` and `length` here is to keep the list in reverse order and store the remaining capacity instead of the maximum.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest definition is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Stack' v = Stack' [v] Int deriving (Show, Functor)
```

You should avoid `length` too because it's `O(n)`.

Use `a : l` instead of `l ++ [a]` - lists can be only efficiently appended at their head, appending to tail is `O(n)`.

Your `push'` can be rewritten by moving `if` inside:

```
push' (Stack' l m) a = Stack' (if m <= length l then l else l ++ [a]) m
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't knowing you can move m out.